# Using `PreferenceActivity` for features only, not settings

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm currently working on an Android app, and looking at the `PreferenceActivity` class and the corresponding layout elements (`PreferenceScreen`, etc.), it appears that it provides much of the functionality that I desire for a major component of the app. However, that component is not a Settings activity per se, and I'm not sure if using Preference stuff for things that aren't technically preferences is a good way to do things. On the other hand, I'd prefer not having to implement all the features that `PreferenceActivity`/etc. provides, so would it be fine to use that framework and just change the layout theme so it doesn't seem like a Settings menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely load/set up the preference layout using the android framework and then save the data using your own implementation of SharedPreferences. [This class](https://github.com/LukasKnuth/connectbot-xoom/blob/master/src/org/connectbot/HostEditorActivity.java) is a good example. Not sure why you would not make it look like a preference screen though. What's wrong with that look?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the look, I was just wondering if there was some Android ideology that would discourage using the normal `PreferenceScreen` look for something that isn't technically a Settings menu.